# I can't use python pip to download any tools and I don't know why

Tags: python, pip

here's a picture of the error I get and the python installations i have

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple things you could try:

1. try reinstalling pip, on windows this can be done with the command:
   `py get-pip.py`
2. Upgrade pip: `py -m pip install --upgrade pip`
3. Try to reinstall python, download a new install package and replace the old installation
4. Manually change your system variables. This is very fiddly and I am not good at it but there are definitely tutorials out there on it
5. Install python from the microsoft store, I know it's not great answer but I've had some other python terminal errors that I managed to fix by installing it from the store

Comment: this is command pip install --upgrade pip

Comment: I added some more ideas and information to my list, I would now reccomend using my first suggestion